# iPhoto & iPhone Album order is different

Tags: iphone, iphoto

I can't seem to find any answers to this, I have around 100 albums in iPhoto on my Mac, they are all synced to my iPhone, but on the phone they are just being displayed in a seeming random order.

I have removed all the photos from the phone and started again, but they go back in the same order.

In iPhoto the albums are actually in alphabetical order, have I've clicked the sort albums option, but this did nothing?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open up iPhoto, and tap the "Edit" button in the top right hand corner.  Then using the horizontal lines that will appear on the right of each album, drag the albums in whichever order.  Hoped this helped!